# Overlapping tabs in question section in SO

Tags: bug, design, new-nav

When a user has too many tabs in **Questions** section the tabs are overlapping with the number of posts counter in SO.
[image: Screenshot]

Also, mouse over on the overlapping tabs hides no. of post[image]